# vue-cli 3.0 devserver proxy not taking effect using axios

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli, quasar-framework

Trying to access production REST services using Axios with a Vue-Cli 3.0 dev server (@vue/cli@3.0.0-rc.10, @vue/cli-service-global@3.0.0-rc.10, quasar framework 0.17.5)

My vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    quasar: {
      theme: 'ios'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://myProduction.server.com'
  }
}
```

I get a 502 bad Gateway error, as listed by Chrome Dev Tool:

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/REST/getText.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I have tried the more detailed config using route key & changeOrigin: true; to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, it looks like using the server's IP address with the port nbr does the trick as far as the Proxy request to be take into account. However, I do now get the following error:
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /REST/getText.php from localhost:8080 to xxx.xxx.0.250:80.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ENOTFOUND).
However ENOTFOUND is not listed the theNodeJS error list.

Any insight about this?